# How to filter a loop with php/smarty?

Tags: php, smarty, shopware

This code shows me all selections I have made.

How can I filter this and only show the selection of a specific Group?

For example `{if $sConfigurator.groupID == 113}`

```
{$configurator = $sArticle.sConfigurator}
{foreach $configurator as $configuratorGroup}
{foreach $configuratorGroup.values as $option}

{if $option.selected}
<div class="selected">
  <div class="group">{$configuratorGroup.groupname}</div>
  <div class="option">{$option.optionname}</div>
</div>
{/if}

{/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Don't quite understand the question. You ask how can you filter the group and then you give an example that just does that? what else do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also not sure what you mean or what configurator your code is about...
Maybe just add the condition to the if?

```
{if $option.selected && $configuratorGroup.id == 113}
    <div class="selected">
        <div class="group">{$configuratorGroup.groupname}</div>
        <div class="option">{$option.optionname}</div>
    </div>
{/if}
```